# How to convert output from matlab to excel

Tags: excel, matlab

This is my program:

```
x= 9;
fprintf(' a z \n _ _ \n');
for a = 0:4
  z =x+a;
fprintf(' %d %d\n',a,z);

end
```

how can i convert the output into excel spreedsheet? or file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get data from Matlab into Excel is writing to a plain text .csv file, then importing that into Excel. To do this, simply open a file

```
fileID = fopen('mydata.csv','w');
```

change the fprintf statements to write to that file

```
x= 9;
fprintf(fileID, ' a, z \n _, _ \n');
for a = 0:4
    z =x+a;
    fprintf(fileID, ' %d, %d\n',a,z);
end
```

and make sure to close the file when you are done

```
fclose(fileID);
```

Import this into Excel and you can save it as an xls file.

Comment: You should note that CSV stands for **comma-separated-value**, and so columns are delimited by **commas**.  I don't see any commas written in your code.

Comment: true, fixed. Excel would still understand the file, but it should probably be a .txt

Comment: how can i save it? as .m?

Comment: @Raldenors - The code above already saves it to file.  You should see a `mydata.csv` file once you finish with the above code.

Comment: @Urs - Good!  Now you get my +1 :)

Comment: @Raldenors - The above code is also the simplest way to get it into Excel.  If you are using MATLAB for Windows, you can also take a look at `xlswrite`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html